# Multiple outputs returned from first function, but when I call them into second function, single output prints

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning python 3 now.

I made a function which checks size of file in directory and return the found directory into next function.

But when I return the output from first function into next function, only single output is printed on second function.

```
#For example

import os
from os import walk
from os import listdir

def first():
    path = input()
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            route = os.path.join(root,file)
            if os.path.isfile(route):
                if os.path.getsize(route) > int(500):
                    print(route)  
    return route

def second(line1):
    print(line1)

def main():
    line1 = first()
    print("---------------") 
    second(line1)  
main()

#Sample Output
C:/Users/Walter/Desktop/Project1 #input
C:/Users/Walter/Desktop/Project1/sample1.txt
C:/Users/Walter/Desktop/Project1/sample1.txt
---------------
C:/Users/Walter/Desktop/Project1/Newfolder/sample1.txt

#What I really want to see
C:/Users/Walter/Desktop/Project1 #input
C:/Users/Walter/Desktop/Project1/sample1.txt
C:/Users/Walter/Desktop/Project1/sample1.txt
---------------
C:/Users/Walter/Desktop/Project1/sample1.txt
C:/Users/Walter/Desktop/Project1/sample1.txt
```

In addition to single output issue, it also gives me entirely different output on second function.

Thanks for any comment in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`route` is a local variable that is assigned within a loop in `first()`: as such, it's going to be assigned multiple values sequentially during the execution of the function, and will end up with whatever value it had on the final iteration of the loop.  It WON'T somehow magically remember every value that was assigned to it, which is what you seem to be expecting.

(Note that `route` may never be assigned a value at all, if the loop executes zero times - for example, if you enter the name of an empty directory.  This would result in an error when you attempt to `return route`.)

If you want to collect multiple values that were assigned to that variable, you have to explicitly do so.  Perhaps:

```
    routes = []
```

at the top to initialize a list,

```
    routes.append(route)
```

when you find a value you want to add to the list, then

```
    return routes
```

at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But the way you listed generates tuple and it is printing all the outputs in the same line instead of what I want from above.